# Django redirect_authenticated_user: True not working

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I'm writing an application in Django 1.11.

`myapp/urls.py` pattern looks like

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), {'redirect_authenticated_user': True}),
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url('^', include('pages.urls')),
    url(r'^pages/', include('pages.urls')),
    url(r'^search/', include('search.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I want logged in user to be redirected when trying to access `/login` page. For that I have set `redirect_authenticated_user` to `True` as per given in documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)

But, when I access `/login` after successful login, it does not redirect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pass [`redirect_authenticated_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) to `as_view()`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True)),
```

> Any arguments passed to as_view() will override attributes set on the class. In this example, we set template_name on the TemplateView. A similar overriding pattern can be used for the url attribute on RedirectView.

From [Simple usage in your URLconf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking into this using Django 2 you would actually use `kwargs` similar to OP.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.login, {'redirect_authenticated_user': True}, name='login'),
]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#views-extra-options